# Load a function from a specific package

Tags: r, namespaces, load, package

I'm loading two R packages `Hmisc` and `TeachingDemos`, which both contain a function called `subplot()`. I load the package `Hmisc` first and it seems that afterwards the `subplot()`-function from `Hmisc` is used. This happens even when I load the library `TeachingDemos` first.

How can I use the function `subplot()` from the `TeachingDemos` package, even if the `Hmisc` package is also loaded?

Comment: Nice question. I directly added an article to my blog on to this topic (in German). http://fenon.de/funktion-aus-einem-bestimmten-r-paket-laden/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `::` operator to specify which function to use like this...

```
TeachingDemos::subplot()
```